# OOP standard practice?

Tags: javascript, oop, underscore.js

I have a question about what is standard practice in object oriented programming. Let's say normally I would write a function like the following :

```
function mapped(array) {
  return _.map(array, function (ele) {
    return ele
  })
}
```

Where array refers to some global variable. Let's say the value of it is :

```
[1,2,3]
```

I want to try to do this instead in object oriented programming. So let's say i have a constructor function :

```
function spider(obj) {
  this.obj = obj
}
```

I want to add the mapped function to the spider prototype. What would be the standard way of re-writing it? Would I leave the mapped function as is, add it to the prototype of spider then call it like so :

```
var object = new spider([4,5,6])
object.mapped(object.obj)
```

Or would I re-write it like so :

```
spider.prototype.mapped = function() {
  return _.map(this.obj, function (ele) {
    return ele
  })
}
```

then just call it like :

```
var object = new spider([4,5,6])
object.mapped()
```

Comment: `object.mapped(object.obj)` doesn't encapsulate `obj` very well.  But asking for *standard practice* for OO in JavaScript is brave. :)

Comment: Well, I've made a small spider solitaire game in Javascript. After talking to a programmer friend, he advised getting familiar with OOP. I'm now converting the game code into OOP style. I have a lot of similar spots to what I posted above which is why I was trying to find out what best practice is.

Comment: Don't put the method on the prototype if it has nothing to do with those instances. In your example, a function that copies arrays has nothing to do with spiders, so leave it as it is. Don't try to use OOP only for its own sake.

Comment: I tried to use a really simple example so it was clear what I was asking. I would be doing quite a bit more than just copying an array. The array I would be iterating over would be on the 'this' object of the spider instance.